# Pizza dough dipping in middle during proofing

Tags: dough, pizza, yeast, proofing

Yesterday afternoon I made some pizza dough for use on Friday (tomorrow).

I mixed in all of the ingredients after blooming the yeast then split the dough into 4 equal parts and placed them in oiled Tupperware. I covered the containers with cling film and placed them in the fridge.

I checked on them today and saw one of the four has got a steep dip in the middle of the dough. The others are fine.

Have I done something wrong? Is this normal? Will it ruin the pizza? If so, can I salvage it?

Note: I'm currently out of the house so can't take a photo. I'll add one ASAP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general you should be fine, I would give this dough more time to warm/"re-proof" on the counter before shaping/ baking.

I've seen something similar in other doughs, but I don't know what caused it. I don't expect much proofing in the fridge, and I've seen some weird stages when I try to slow a proof in the fridge (start a dough then finish it the next morning.)

If I was forced to guess..

1. This dough may have been handled more roughly
2. Colder spot in the fridge
3. Condensation on the plastic wrap dripping an slowing raise in one spot
4. Moved at some point, popping the center of the dough

Comment: The cold spot could be it. The other doughs were at the middle or bottom of the fridge whereas this was right at the top.

Comment: I know in my fridge Top shelf, Back, middle is the coldest spot. I'll occasionally find frozen items there. I hope to cooked up ok.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with RunThor.  You have proofed the yeast as you stated so we know that it was all alive.  I've not heard of allowing pizza dough to rise in the fridge but as long as the particular species of yeast can live at that cold temp (which you know it does) you are fine.  It was probably just a colder spot that fell below the yeasts tolerance.  I'd take it out, and allow it to rise at a regular bread temperature (slightly warmer than room).  See what it does.  If it does not rise at all, most likely the yeast in that round is dead.  But I'm sure it will be fine.  My fridge will actually freeze things that touch its back wall.  Even if it "fell" while in the fridge when you touch the dough it should still be springy.  I make pizza almost once a week, as well as brioche type dough's.